# Log in to website using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to log in to http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb using python and selenium.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver

session = webdriver.Chrome()
session.get('https://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb')

# REMOVE POP-UP
timezone_popup_ok_button = session.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="yesBtn"]')
timezone_popup_ok_button.click()

# FILL OUT FORMS
usr_field = session.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Username"]')
usr_field.clear()
WebDriverWait(session, 10).until(EC.visibility_of(usr_field))
usr_field.send_keys('myUsername')
pwd_field = session.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Password"]')
pwd_field.clear()
pwd_field.send_keys('myPassword')
login_button = session.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signInBtn"]')
login_button.click()
```

I'm getting the following error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

when trying to execute

```
usr_field.send_keys('myUsername')
```

The usr_field element seems to be visible if I'm viewing it with the inspector tool, however I'm not 100% sure here.

I'm using this script (with some modifications) successfully on other sites, but this one is giving me a real headache and I can't seem to find the answer anywhere on the net.

Would appreciate if someone could help me out here!

Comment: step one: start a debugger and find out which element is not visible

Comment: Put some sleep to leave the time for the elements ti be loaded.

Comment: @SamirSadek Don't use sleeps... sleeps are a bad practice. Use `WebDriverWait` instead.

Comment: Sure. You right.

Comment: Have you tried waiting for the element to be visible? http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: I have tried both time.sleep(1) as well as explicit waits. The updated script (see above) is now raising a timeout exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will resolve the issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver


session = webdriver.Chrome()
session.get('https://sports.williamhill.com/bet/en-gb')

# REMOVE POP-UP
timezone_popup_ok_button = session.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@id="yesBtn"]')
timezone_popup_ok_button.click()

# FILL OUT FORMS

user_element = session.find_element_by_name("tmp_username")
user_element.click()

actual_user_elm = session.find_element_by_name("username")
actual_user_elm.send_keys("myUsername")


password_element = session.find_element_by_id("tmp_password")
password_element.click()

actual_pass_element = session.find_element_by_name("password")
actual_pass_element.send_keys("myPassword")

login_button = session.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="signInBtn"]')
login_button.click()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, absolutely brilliant. Much appreciated. Thank you!